# How to print the actual name of the file to the console (C++)

Tags: c++, terminal, console

I am using the terminal and C++. My program is opening a text file and doing various things with it. However, towards the very end I just want to print out the file name. How do I do that? I know that `argc` will look at a certain argument, but this still just looks at the number of the argument. I need the actual `string` name.

Comment: It's in the `char** argv` passed to `main`.

Comment: How did you open the file? You must have have the string in hand then.

Comment: Ron, Sorry I don't think I was clear. For example if I had a .cpp called test and and textfile called file.txt. Then I would input `./test file.txt` and it should output `file.txt`

Comment: Search for command line arguments.

Comment: bmargulies, I already know how to open the file, but I am trying to print out the name of the file that was passed in when I am trying to run my .cpp file.

Comment: `cout << argv[0] << endl;`

Comment: cout << argv[0] << '\n'. Every time you use `endl` in an example, a baby seal dies.

Comment: that worked yacc!! Thanks!

Comment: nooo... *sniff* @MartinBroadhurst

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To print out the first argument (in your case the `file.txt` file name supplied as an argument) use the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    if (argc > 1){
        std::cout << argv[1];
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "No arguments passed in.";
    }
}
```

If you execute the program via: **./test file.txt** the console output will be:

> file.txt

Please note that `argv[0]` will print out the name and the (calling) path of your executable which in your case is `./test`, not the name of your text file (argument).